# AsyncLazy implementation for web requests

Tags: c#, async-await

I have used generic asynchronous cache implementation described here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/15/asynclazyt/. The drawback of this solution is that `Task.Factory.StartNew` (as well as `Task.Run`) creates new threads on threadpool without original web request having any knowledge of it, thus possibly leading to starting new threads and threadpool starvation. So is there any possible modification so that the class could be used for both desktop and web applications? For web request using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` instead of `Task.Run` / `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Thanks for any help / ideas.

```
private static async Task<T> GetTask(Func<T> valueFactory)
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
    {
        T value = default(T);
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((_) => value = valueFactory());
        await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(valueFactory).Result;
    }
}

public AsyncLazy(Func<T> valueFactory) : base(() => GetTask(valueFactory))
{
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is something you need to worry about? How the tasks are scheduled on the thread pool.

Comment: I think you're mixing some concepts here. The point of `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is not to prevent threadpool starvation. It's used to keep track of tasks running in background so that ASP.NET will give them a chance to complete before recycling your AppDomain

Comment: That tutorial your reading is 7 years old, the TPL framework has moved on since that was written. For a start [it's not advised to use `Task.Factory.SartNew` anymore](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). This whole thing smells of premature optimisation, which is the [*root of all evil*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth). Why do you feel you need to do this at all? I'd imagine there is a better solution to you [**actual** problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd like to emphasize that what you're trying to do is probably a bad idea. `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` will **not** prevent the creation of threads or limit threadpool starvation. It actually runs your work on the threadpool behind the scenes. Its purpose is just to keep track of background tasks that are currently running, so that ASP.NET can wait for them to complete before recycling the AppDomain (which may happen for instance when you make a change in the web.config file).
Also, to use `HostingEnvironment` you need a reference to `System.Web.dll`, so this is not a helper you should use for instance for a console application.

That said, let's say that this is really what you want to do. The first issue in your code is that you're calling `.Result`. **This** will cause threadpool starvation. Instead, await the task (also, you should always use `Task.Run` unless you have a good reason to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. If you don't know what those reasons are, this is a sign you should **definitely** use `Task.Run` instead).

The second issue is: how to wait for the item scheduled on the HostingEnvironment? For that, you should use `TaskCompletionSource`. Your code would then look like:

```
private static Task<T> GetTask<T>(Func<T> valueFactory)
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);

        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            tcs.SetResult(valueFactory());
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    return Task.Run(valueFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`TaskFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory?view=netframework-4.7.2) has constructors that accepts a [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.7.2) ([`TaskFactory(CancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions, TaskContinuationOptions, TaskScheduler)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskFactory__ctor_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCreationOptions_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskContinuationOptions_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_) and [`TaskFactory(TaskScheduler)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskFactory__ctor_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_)).

> The [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.7.2) class also serves as the extension point for all customizable scheduling logic.

Override the abstract methods [`QueueTask(Task)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.queuetask?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_QueueTask_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_), [`TryDequeue(Task)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.trydequeue?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_TryDequeue_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_), and [`TryExecuteTaskInline(Task, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.tryexecutetaskinline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_TryExecuteTaskInline_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_System_Boolean_) to forward to [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_Hosting_HostingEnvironment_QueueBackgroundWorkItem_System_Func_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__)

In the web application you use the `TaskFactory` with your own `TaskScheduler` in the console application you use the default `TaskFactory`.  And in this case you have good reasons to use [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskFactory_StartNew_System_Action_) instead of [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2).